# How to verify mod_proxy settings?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have an apache httpd (v2.2) in domain aaa.bbb.ccc with mod_proxy settings:

```
/team http://xxx.yyy.zzz/team
```

It just pass url in http://aaa.bbb.ccc/team to http://xxx.yyy.zzz/team.
My question is any external tool or any ways to verify my running config is identical to my mod_proxy.conf ?

I am developing the proxy update tools, to verify tools setting proxy correctly is very important.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how the running configuration can possibly *not* be what is in mod_proxy.conf.

You seem to suspect that your tools may be liable to spatter proxy directives into other files. If so, surely the answer is to design them so they can't, and test them to ensure they won't? Using a run time check seems like just a very late way to debug your tools.